# ngInit VS. Firing Controller Function - What are the Downsides?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a couple questions regarding the use of `ng-init` - I've see many people online recommend substituting `ng-init` for running the desired function as soon as the controller is ready.

What if I have two vies that use the same controller, but I only want *one* of the views to trigger a specific controller function, like so

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    {{ someStuff }}
</div>

<div ng-controller="myController" ng-init="run()">
    {{ someOtherStuff }}
</div>
```

app.js

```
.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.someStuff = 'ABC';
    $scope.run = function(){
        $scope.someOtherStuff = 'XYZ';
    }
}
```

In this scenario, what is the real downside of using ng-init to call `run()`? Would there be any issues if `run()` was an asynchronous function?

In my opinion this seems to the the job just fine, but I may have glossed over why this is a bad idea. Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I personally avoid using `ng-init` unless there are NO other ways that I can solve my problem. That's really what `ng-init` is supposed to be used for, but you'll find a plethora of bad usages of `ng-init` everywhere you look.

As per the `ng-init` documentation:

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

A better idea would be to simply use another controller and map your templates 1:1 with the controllers.

Comment: Thansk Ben, I thought of creating another controller but I'd also like to keep the code as short as possible - suppose this can't be helped if I'm going for best-practices

Comment: Although they did mention 'injecting data via server side scripting', which kind of fits what I'd like to do via an ajax call. Does that mean my use of ng-init gets a pass? Hmmm

Comment: @KuraiBankusu, if you're making an ajax call, that should be done through a service that you inject into your controller. If you only want some of the data from the service initialized then you can choose what you want to resolve via a promise.

Comment: @KuraiBankusu, I would say it your usage of `ng-init` does not get a pass here. Let's put it this way... I've worked on multiple large-scale (100+ controllers) AngularJS applications. I've NEVER used `ng-init` in an application. I would take two controllers with similar logic over an improper use of `ng-init` any day.

Comment: I know services and promises. I'm really wondering what the issue would be if I invoked my ajax call via a `ng-init`

Comment: Fair enough, but is invoking a promise an improper use of `ng-init`? Maybe I should post another question

Comment: @KuraiBankusu, I would leave it at this. If you're thinking of using `ng-init` first ask yourself is there is another way to do what you're trying to do. If there's another way, do that. If there _really_ isn't another way, use `ng-init`.

Comment: I was working on writing an answer but this one seems to say *most* of the things I was.  I do want to add another point, however:  `ng-init` is a directive with priority level 450, so it would be affected by other directives present in the DOM which may have higher priority, or by controller functions that run before directives are compiled.  This can potentially cause unexpected results.

Comment: also, any time you are triggering application logic from the HTML, you are creating an unnecessary, confusing abstraction and tight coupling.  You are creating a condition whereby someone looking at the code in the future has to see a `run()` function in one file and find that function in another file to interpret what it does.  It is less clear what to expect of the component.

Comment: @Claies, thank you for the extra clarification. Very solid points.